# Can the WhatsApp group icon or title be locked?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there a way for a WhatsApp admin to lock the group icon and title? As of this time, any group member can change the group icon or title.

Comment: [Check out the new answer added](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/195823/59238) - now it's possible

Answer (score 3):

No. It is impossible using the standard app.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard app"? Are there parallel apps from WhatsApp or something?

Comment: Of course, there is Whatsapp+ an app that let you customize various settings of Whatsapp. But it is an apk, and you have to replace the official whatsapp app with this one.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 and it's possible!**

WhatsApp admins can stop the members from editing group info. The feature appears to be recently added to WhatsApp. While searching, I [found that](https://www.techmesto.com/whatsapp-edit-group-info-restriction/) it is functional since version 2.18.135. What I have installed right now is 2.18.141. So, it should be rolled out to everybody by now.

1. Open group info.
2. Look for the new option "Group Settings".
3. Change the **Edit group info** setting from *All participants* to *Only admins*.

I can also read some sites reporting that WhatsApp beta also has a new option where all members can be muted. So, essentially working like a telegram channel where only admins can send messages. Good times ahead!

PS: This question was asked long ago. However, it still ranks well in the search results and I believe that it needs to be updated for the changes WhatsApp has made recently.